# Definite integral is an antiderivative of?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is the following definite integral $\int_a^x w^3dw$ an antiderivative of $w^3$?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes...

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Not quite, not quite, not quite... :)

Comment: A pleasant riposte (+1) for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume $a$ is a constant and $x$ is a variable then $$F(x) = \int_a^x w^3dw$$ is antiderivative of $f(x)=x^3$. The $w$ is just an integration variable.

The expression $\int_a^x w^3dw$ is a function of $x$, not of $w$. You can also write it as   $\int_a^x t^3dt$, it's still a function of $x$ (no matter which variable you use under the integral).